# Can the Nager IT mouse be used with Macbook Pro OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, compatibility

I checked the [FAQ](https://www.nager-it.de/en/informationen/faq) and am uncertain about limitations of mouse support on Mac OS X in general.

Comment: It's a USB mouse.. it must be compliant to USB HID guidelines. Why would it *not* work? Have you asked the creators?

Comment: 8-button mouse would need 3rd party support, but that's just a standard ⅔ button + scroll. No issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed that it works by try. Extreme unfairness in production of hardware and extreme fairness are compatible.